# Need Information on XslCompiledTransform in Plain English

Tags: xslcompiledtransform

Does anybody have any links that explain proper implementation of the XSLCompiledTransform? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx